# Emulating function keys in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, emulation

I have been using this to emulate key presses:

```
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, keyName, YES);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
```

For letters I can use: kVK_ANSI_A, but how can I press function keys? It auto-fills: kVK_F2 for the F2 key and so on, but it definitely does not change the brightness as expected.

I have been reading up on function keys and how function keys are treated differently, and I tried things like hitting Fn first but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate those keys (kind of complicated), or just change the system brightness (considerably simpler)?

Comment: Well I would like to change the system brightness, but also play and skip songs with F8 and F9. Can I get all the functionality of those keys without emulating them?

Comment: Yes — all of this functionality is available through more direct (and reliable!) means than simulating keypresses.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I would like to use keystrokes if possible. I am trying to build a virtual keyboard...